# do we say in a marathon or through a marathon?

Tags: grammar

Can I say "Have you ever sprinted in a marathon?" or should I say "Have you every sprinted through a marathon?"

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use the word *sprint* at all in that sentence because *sprint* means [to run as fast as you can over a short distance, either in a race or because you are in a great hurry to get somewhere](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sprint) while a marathon is a long-distance race in which your focus isn't really on running as fast as you can throughout the race.

I would say any of the following:

> **Have** you ever **run** a marathon?
>
> **Have** you ever **run** in a marathon?
>
> **Have** you ever **taken part** in a marathon?

Take note that the present perfect tense of the verb *run* is *have run*.

Comment: Yes. And perhaps "Have you ever completed a marathon?", which maybe was what "have you ever run through a marathon" was getting at.

Comment: @WS2 Yes, that's a great point. Although I wonder if you can say that you ran a marathon if you didn't actually complete it.

Comment: "Have you ever sprinted in a marathon?" is totally acceptable, though probably not with the meaning OP intends.

Comment: I agree with @EdwinAshworth. They might have sprinted a short distance (excuse the tautology) but ran/jogged the rest.